# PostgreSQL : Update Target table from another table based on a joined column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, inner-join

I need to update table3 from table1 using a joined column from table2 in postreSQL, I can think of a common table expression to achieve it , but this doesn't seem to execute.

```
A>existing target data **table3**

col1 code  uid 
A     123  abc
B     123  cef

B>lookup table data **table2**

id uid 
4  abc
5  cef
4  klm 
5  mnp 


C>new data in stage **table1**

col1  code  uid 
C     123   klm
D     123   mnp

D>result final target data **table3** (updated with table1)

col1  code  uid 
C     123   abc
D     123   def
```

**Explanation** :-

uid from table3 is looked up in table2 which creates data
after join as

```
code id col1
123  4  A
123  5  B
```

Now stage table1 is looked up into table2 to create data after join as

```
code id col1
123  4  C
123  5  D
```

and hence based on  primary keys code + id then value of col1 is updated to

```
col1  code  uid 
C     123   abc
D     123   def
```

**Tried SQL Code**

```
with 
  sm as 
    (
     select 
     s.col1
    ,s.code
    ,ssi.id from stage.table3 s 
     join stage.table2 ssi on s.uid = ssi.uid ),
  cte as (
     select 
     k.col1
    ,k.code
    ,ss.id 
     from stage.table1 k
     join stage.table2 ss on k.uid = ss.uid )
  update sm set col1 = cte.col1 
  from cte where 
  cte.id = sm.id and cte.code = sm.code;
```

**DDL for test data**

```
create table table3(col1, code, uid) as 
(
select 'A',123,'abc'
union all 
select 'B', 123,'cef'
);


create table table2(id,uid) as 
(
select 4,'abc'
union all 
select 5,'cef'
union all 
select 4,'klm'
union all 
select 5,'mnp'
);


create table table1(col1, code, uid) as 
(
select 'C',123,'klm'
union all 
select 'D',123,'mnp'
);
```

Please Note :- target table3 doesn't have an id column, it needs to be derived by joining to table2 based on uid.

Appreciate your help on this

**EDITS**

I tried rewriting the query as below and it works. Any comments and suggestions are welcome.

**Solution**

```
update table3 sm
set col1 = p.col1
from table1 p  -- join stage table to lookup table to retrieve id
join table2 ss on p.uid = ss.uid 
where exists 
(select from table3 smi    -- join target table to lookup table to retrieve id
join table2 ssi on smi.uid = ssi.uid 
where  -- filter and join both 
ss.id = ssi.id and 
sm.code = smi.code and 
sm.uid = smi.uid and
sm.code = p.code
);
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @GordonLinoff,Tried making the question more descriptive, Does this make sense ?

Comment: I was able to get the solution by re framing the query as mentioned in description

Answer (score 0):

i think the logic you want is:

```
update table3 t3
set col1 = t1.col1
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.uid = t1.uid
where t3.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but table3 doesn't have an id column ,it has to be derived by joining from table2 ,Is that possible to accommodate or I missed something

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `table2.id` is unique or the primary key, then I think the logic is:

```
update stage.table3 s 
    set s.col1 = 
    from stage.table2 ssi join
         stage.table1 k
         on k.uid = ss.uid 
    where s.uid = ssi.uid;
```

I will say that it would be much simpler to figure out the correct query based on sample data and a description of what you want to do.  The sample code is actually not particularly helpful.

Comment: added explanation and desired result